# Should I use a global variable to share socket.io instance across entire server

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

The following is my server.js file in my node.js application. I want my socket.io instance to be accessed by other files on my server in order to emit events from my API `(listingRoutesApi, userRoutesApi etc.) (refer to code)`.

**The problem I have is that my routes are declared before the server is created; however, the socket.io instance is created after the server is created.**

**The solution I've used is to declare a global `io` variable that will allow me to emit events from anywhere within my web app like so:**

```
global.io.of('/analytics').to(listing._id).emit('message', "There was a post.");
```

**My question is: are there any pitfalls / dangers from doing this and will I encounter any scalability issues in the long-term? Additionally, is there a better way of achieving my objective?**

Code within my server.js file:

```
const app = express();    

app.use('/api', listingRoutesApi);
app.use('/api', userRoutesApi);
app.use('/api', imageRoutesApi);
// ...plenty more endpoints here...

app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, "/dist")));
app.use(history());
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, "/dist")));

const server = app.listen(port, () => { console.log('server started ' + port); });

/* Start socket. */
global.io = socketio(server);

const analytics = global.io.of("/analytics");

analytics.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('join', (data) => {
        socket.join(data.room);
        analytics.in(data.room).emit('message', `New user joined ${data.room}`);
    });
    socket.on('leave', (data) => {
        analytics.in(data.room).emit('message', `User leaving ${data.room}`);
        socket.leave(data.room);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

I'm asking this question since [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676815/nodejs-socketio-multiple-files) answers a similar question by declaring a `getIOInstance` function and passes it to all modules that require it. While, it works, it doesn't feel very elegant and seems a little unnecessary given I expect to only ever have exactly one socket.io instance in my application.

Additionally, I would assume the challenge I'm having is a very common one; however, I haven't been able to find many solutions to address it and none that suggest using a global variable.

Comment: @estus what issues do you think I'll encounter by using a global variable?

Comment: Try to search 'why globals are bad in js'. You will have a big list of issues. Node.js introduced modules exactly to get rid of globals where they are unsuitable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Node.js is a modular environment. Modules are suppose to address some flaws that globals have.

Modules naturally provide singleton instances, in case there's a need to have only one instance:

*app.js*

```
module.export = express();
```

*server.js*

```
const app = require('./app');

// can go to app.js if configured but unlistened app is needed for reusability or testing
app.use(/* router */);

module.export = app.listen(...);
```

*socketio.js*

```
const server = require('./server');

module.export = socketio(server);
```

*index.js*

```
const app = require('./app');
const io = require('./socketio');
...
```

Express also provides a container for application global dependencies, [application settings table](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set). It can be used everywhere application instance is available, e.g. as `req.app.get(...)` inside middlewares. Accessing Express application instance outside middlewares won't be a problem if it's a singleton as well:

*app.js*

```
module.export = express();
```

*index.js*

```
const app = require('./app');

app.use(/* router */);
...

const server = app.listen(...);
const io = socketio(server);

app.set('io', io);

// available as req.app.get('io') inside middlewares
// and as require('./app').get('io') outside them
```

Comment: Pardon me if I'm a bit slow here but wouldn't I need to pass the "server" within app.js to socketio.js in order to create a new socketio instance? Also, assuming that was true, wouldn't I still encounter my initial issue of having the routes declared before my server is created, which means I wouldn't be able to import the socketio.js file into any of the modules above `app.listen(...)`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to explain this. This is solved with a singleton for Express instance. This modular setup makes testing easier rather than doing this in one single file. You can mock modules or spy on them if needed.

Comment: That last edit you made including `app.listen(...)` made everything clearer for me :) Although, I must say all the require statements are making my head spin a little haha

Comment: It takes a while to become comfortable with modular approach. I added the explanation for Express settings. It's idiomatic to Express but not necessarily better than using modules alone to share app global data.

Comment: @EstusFlask  i use this in my another route `let io = require("../../app").get("io");`  it got an error require(...).get is not a function **I use this inside of express post request**

Comment: @RohitNishad Debug what `require("../../app")` is. It should be Express instance. This is what `module.export = express()` in app.js is supposed to do. This is shown in the answer.

Comment: @EstusFlask my `app.js`  is not export anything. I just want to access `io` from anywhere is there any other way.

Comment: It needs to export Express instance in order to access io *anywhere*. If you want to do this in post handler, Express instance is already available as `req.app.get('io')`, also explained above.

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks its work. but I want a recommendation that I am building a notification system is this right to use `io`  globally.

Comment: To use with Express only you can stick to using `app.get('io')` as suggested. You can import it directly from socketio.js module, too. And thanks for fixed typos.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214370/discussion-between-rohit-nishad-and-estus-flask).

Comment: @JCraine The router goes after `app = express()` but before `app.listen`, as it's always done in Express apps. I skipped `app.use` because they don't affect the subject. Avoiding circular dependency is the point of the answer. CD is possible if you try to access `io` by importing the instance from a module. This is what `get('io')` is for.

Comment: @EstusFlask Apologies, I deleted my previous comment before I saw your reply - thank you for your answers - that worked for me. Legend. For anyone coming in, I was asking where to place the router.